# replace subject with variable text

Tags: vba, outlook

So i am working on a project to automatically send e-mails with an attachment. the subject has to have a specific name but up till now i cannot get the last part to work.

```
   Private WithEvents Mail As Outlook.MailItem
Private WithEvents Inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set Inspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub Inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
  If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    Set Mail = Inspector.CurrentItem
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Mail_AttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment)
  Mail.subject = "[ediDocManager CON TOR " + Attachment.DisplayName
```

if i run this code i will get as subject ""[ediDocManager CON TOR " + Attachment.DisplayName.pdf" but i want the pdf to be replaced with a"]"

how do i get this done?

Answer (score 1):

In VBA you concatenate strings using `&` sign not `+`. And you can use `Replace` function for the PDF part.
Try this:

```
Mail.subject = "[ediDocManager CON TOR " & Replace(Attachment.DisplayName, "pdf", "]")
```

Hope this helps!